# Get Max item in jinja2 groupby?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to get the max item from a groupby statement in jinaj2.

For example

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = [
        {'var': 1, 'var2': 2},
        {'var': 2, 'var2': 2},
        {'var': 3, 'var2': 2},
        {'var': 1, 'var2': 4},
        {'var': 2, 'var2': 4},
        {'var': 3, 'var2': 4},
    ]
    return render_template('test.html', data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

{% for group in data|groupby('var2') %}
 {{ group.grouper }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

This just prints

```
2
4
```

I would like it to just print `4`.

This sort of works

```
{% set l = [] %}
{% for group in data|groupby('var2') %}
 {{l.append(group.grouper)}}
<br>
{% endfor %}
{{ l|max}}
```

But it prints

```
None
None
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `do` extension in the environment of Jinja2 in your flask app.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = [
        {'var': 1, 'var2': 2},
        {'var': 2, 'var2': 2},
        {'var': 3, 'var2': 2},
        {'var': 1, 'var2': 4},
        {'var': 2, 'var2': 4},
        {'var': 3, 'var2': 4},
    ]

    app.jinja_env.add_extension("jinja2.ext.do")

    return render_template('test.html', data=data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

{% set l = [] %}
{% for group in data | groupby("var2") %}
    {% do l.append(group.grouper) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ l | max }}
```

Or you can do `groupby` and `max` in view function and pass the max item to the template file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own filter in your Flask app and then call that filter in your HTML template like the one below. Take note, the function name you created must be the same as the filter name.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = [
        {'var': 1, 'var2': 2},
        {'var': 2, 'var2': 2},
        {'var': 3, 'var2': 2},
        {'var': 1, 'var2': 4},
        {'var': 2, 'var2': 4},
        {'var': 3, 'var2': 4},
    ]
    return render_template('test.html', data=data)


@app.template_filter()
def maximum(_list):
    try:
        return max(_list)[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

---

test.html

```
{{ data|groupby('var2')|maximum }}
```